# Custom UserDetailsService not being called unless I have formLogin()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Authentication is being done by another system, so I get the **userId** and **Role** in the `HttpRequest`. So all I want to do is set the **user** details and `role` authorities (for **authorization**) without having a **login form**.

So I created a custom implementation of **UserDetailsService**... but it doesn't get called and therefore the roles aren't set

How can I set it up so that the  custom `UserDetailsService` gets called?
Or any other ways on how to achieve this ?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
http
.addFilterBefore(encodingFilter,CsrfFilter.class)
.addFilterAfter(new MdcFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class)
.addFilterAfter(new ParameterSanitizerFilter(), MdcFilter.class)
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole(StringConstants.USER_ROLE, StringConstants.MANAGER_ROLE);
//.formLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by following this example:
http://www.learningthegoodstuff.com/2014/12/spring-security-pre-authentication-and.html